# Setup alert in LUIS (Azure Cognitive Service) to track user activity

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-bot-service, azure-language-understanding

I want to know there's some way I can set up an email alert on the LUIS port if any users are changing established intent and utterances.

I need this feature because many users are able to access/edit my LUIS app using the company's single-sign-on, so I want to set up an alert on the portal if any user add/edit intent is in the current app, then I will get an email alert.

Please suggest ways that I can do this.

Comment: Your users should not be able to access / edit LUIS app! The problem here is the way you are managing rights for your LUIS resource in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Nicholas is correct. Your users should NOT have access to your app.

There is nothing in the LUIS app on LUIS.ai that will send an email or notification any time the app is changed, because the only people who should have access to it are the developers.

You need to request from your admin to ensure you and any devs on your bot are the only contributers to your LUIS app.

[image: LUIS Key Management]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-keys

Comment: thanks for your reply. user management and their roles are already in place for my app but there still cases where we have to provide access to our managers to train LUIS for some utterances on the prod environment so after that we need to sync up manually our staging with prod. And that's why I'm talking about developing some alert system to let developers know about any changes.